# Modifying list with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter a list with linq, the problem is that when filtering a list with linq it only returns the result of the filter, and im looking for a way to modify the list rather than getting a result of the filter, because im doing it on a foreach.

Here is the foreach im doing:

```
foreach(Filtro f in filtros)
{
    if(f.Activo)
    {
        switch(f.TipoFiltro)
        {
            case TipoFiltro.nombre:
                jugadoresFiltrados.Where(j => j.Nombre.Contains(f.ContenidoFiltro));
                break;
            case TipoFiltro.equipo:
                jugadoresFiltrados.Where(j => j.EquipoJugador.Contains(f.ContenidoFiltro));
                break;
            case TipoFiltro.mundial:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This won't work because I'm not modifiying the jugadoresFiltrados list.

Comment: What's the type of `jugadoresFiltrados`?

Comment: It is a list of players, the question was answered but thanks for your interest anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns the filtered list, it doesn't change the collection:

> Returns an IEnumerable that contains elements from the input sequence that satisfy the condition.

So you need to assign the filtered list back to the collection, for example:

```
jugadoresFiltrados = jugadoresFiltrados.Where(j => j.Nombre.Contains(f.ContenidoFiltro));
```

If `jugadoresFiltrados` **is** a List, you will need to call ToList() as well:

```
jugadoresFiltrados = jugadoresFiltrados.Where(j => j.Nombre.Contains(f.ContenidoFiltro)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Sorry if this was a dumb question but I'm learning linq.